# Auto renewable subscription in my app in app store no longer works

Tags: swift, app-store, in-app-subscription

I accepted the new license agreement and I think it doesn't work anymore after that. Anyone know about that?

Comment: What Apple does stays with Apple.  Ask your question at Apple's developer's forums.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask this question. Also, in the future, always include a bit more detail in the questions you ask at SO.

Comment: thank you for your interest i will ask you where and what to ask next.

Answer (score 0):

I can not make a purchase because I used it as a test device before. You can try to purchase from a device that you do not use as a tester.